# MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() doesn't show file in Windows Explorer even though file exists on phone

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

The method createNewFile() returns true and shows the location of the file on my phone. The file shows up in the file manager of my phone but does not in Explorer.

Basically I call createNewFile() on the File object:

```
File file = new File(path);
try {
        file.createNewFile());
```

I write to the file and then call:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

This should show it in Windows Explorer and this has happened with another app but it doesn't with this app and I do not see any relevant difference. Furthermore, neither disconnecting and reconnecting the USB cable or restarting my phone causes the file to show up in Explorer.

Comment: your question completely unclear. Do you mean to say the file you created is not visible when you connect your device to pc using usb cable?

Comment: Yes and how was that not clear? It says it in both the title and twice in the post: "The file shows up in the file manager of my phone but does not in Explorer." and "This should show it in Windows Explorer and this has happened with another app but it doesn't with this app". Is this why you downvoted?

Comment: The thing that is unclear is that how `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` is linked to windows explorer as what I read from MediaScanner Documentation is that your newly created file will be available to apps that implement `MediaScannerConnection` Class as defined in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void broadCastToMediaScanner(Context context, File file) {

    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```